# Retrieve another language of a Wikipedia page

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Task: We have Wikipedia English page and need to retrieve the same page address in Russian.

I know the Semantic Web solution - use simple query to DbPedia, but I am curious whether  there are traditional solutions. I have asked the same question in [semanticoverflow.com](http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/2166/retrieve-another-language-wikipedia-url) where Toby Inkster suggested to parse http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colugo?action=raw results (there are other languages links in the bottom), but this way is too inefficient. Are there any other ways or DbPedia is the one real option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wikipedia has an [extensive API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API), which can provide language links information among others. In this particular case, you're looking for `api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&titles=...`. [See here for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox#action=query&prop=langlinks&format=json&lllimit=100&lllang=ru&titles=Colugo).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when finding the Japanese (ja) title equivalence for page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aframomum_corrorima

```
import json
import requests

site = "enwiki"  # For English queries, set `&sites=enwiki`
page = "Aframomum_corrorima"
trg_lang = "ja"

url = f"https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites={site}&titles={page}&languages={trg_lang}&format=json"

result = json.loads(requests.get(url).content.decode('utf8'))

translations = [result['entities'][k]['labels'] for k in result['entities']]
print(translations)
```

[out]:

```
[{'ja': {'language': 'ja', 'value': 'コロリマ'}}]
```

Then you'll find that the [https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=コロリマ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%AA%E3%83%9E) isn't written yet but the wikidata API is able to find the right entity translation.

To extract all the possible links, do something like:

```
url = f"https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites={site}&titles={page}&prop=langlinks&format=json"

result = json.loads(requests.get(url).content.decode('utf8'))

links = [result['entities'][e]['sitelinks'] for e in result['entities'].keys()]

print(json.dumps(links))
```

[out]:

```
[
    {
        "amwiki": {
            "site": "amwiki",
            "title": "\\u12ae\\u1228\\u122a\\u121b",
            "badges": []
        },
        "cebwiki": {
            "site": "cebwiki",
            "title": "Aframomum corrorima",
            "badges": []
        },
        "commonswiki": {
            "site": "commonswiki",
            "title": "Category:Aframomum corrorima",
            "badges": []
        },
        "elwiki": {
            "site": "elwiki",
            "title": "Aframomum corrorima",
            "badges": []
        },
        "enwiki": {
            "site": "enwiki",
            "title": "Aframomum corrorima",
            "badges": []
        },
        "eswiki": {
            "site": "eswiki",
            "title": "Aframomum corrorima",
            "badges": []
        },
        "frwiki": {
            "site": "frwiki",
            "title": "Aframomum corrorima",
            "badges": []
        },
        "kowiki": {
            "site": "kowiki",
            "title": "\\ucf54\\ub7ec\\ub9ac\\ub9c8",
            "badges": []
        },
        "lawiki": {
            "site": "lawiki",
            "title": "Aframomum corrorima",
            "badges": []
        },
        "specieswiki": {
            "site": "specieswiki",
            "title": "Aframomum corrorima",
            "badges": []
        },
        "svwiki": {
            "site": "svwiki",
            "title": "Korarima",
            "badges": []
        },
        "ukwiki": {
            "site": "ukwiki",
            "title": "Aframomum corrorima",
            "badges": []
        },
        "viwiki": {
            "site": "viwiki",
            "title": "Aframomum corrorima",
            "badges": []
        },
        "warwiki": {
            "site": "warwiki",
            "title": "Aframomum corrorima",
            "badges": []
        }
    }
]
```