# How to get the Entity of Wikipedia in other language through MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I have a list of English Wikipedia title (Wikipedia items) and want to get the their Chinese title. Is there any python methods through MediaWiki can do it?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're looking for a "language translate" API callable from Python? Look at https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-translation-python3

Comment: Thank you! it's a way to get the results. I hope to do this through wikidata and I found a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724450/how-to-get-the-name-of-wikipedia-article-in-other-language. But I don't know how to do it with python calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about article names (usually H1 in HTML or extractable from URL) then go to [Petscan](https://petscan.wmflabs.org) and use the following settings:

- Set English language for the interface (right next to the globe on the top)
- Categories - Wikidata
- Other sources - Manual list - list your English Wikipedia titles in the column (the first letter of the name should be capitalized, no stop sign needed)
- Other sources - Wiki - enwiki
- Other sources - Use wiki - (the last option) - znwiki (if you need a certain subversion of Chinese, you have to find its ISO code and replace the "zn")
- Click on Do it! - it should generate the list below